Why are languages commonly structured as trees?
I could define a language as a collection of symbols or elements, with rules for putting them together.
When I say "putting them together", it sounds like there is only one way to do that. In other words, we don't have multiple kinds of combination.
Let's assume when we put things together, it always has an order. So (a, b) is different from (b, a).
Let's assume we can put multiple things together; for example, (a, b, c, d).
When we put things together, that forms a new thing. And we can put that thing together with other things. For example, (d, (e, f, g)) is putting together d and (e, f, g).
This set-up naturally leads to tree structures. A composite thing has edges to the things it combines.

Why do languages so frequently have tree structures?
Is there something about the features languages need to have that prevents them from having other structures?

Re your "when we put things together, it always has an order. So (a, b) is different from (b, a)", it's well-known in the language of set theory, {a, b} is same as {b, a} in terms of order. A tree structure from your mereological construction is natural since parthood with foundation is ingrained in our everyday lived lifeworld horizonal experience. Though in theory nothing prevents a public language to be anti-foundational like a non-directed cyclic graph, anti-foundation set theory, or even a probabilistic quantum field...

Some, but not all, of the structure of a sentence can be displayed in a tree. For example, pronouns often refer back to a noun already introduced in an earlier clause, where the earlier clause is neither an ancestor nor descendant of the pronoun in the parse tree. If you added this connection to the diagram then it would no longer be a tree.

"Why do languages so frequently have tree structures?" By your very own definition of language ("I could define a language ...") it seems like a vacuous truth.

You might be interested in linguistics.stackexchange

The grammar of most modern languages is recursive (e.g., an expression in C can contain expressions: <expression> ::= <assignment-expression> | <expression> , <assignment-expression>) and hence have circular elements.

The tree isn't the structure of the language; it's the structure of your representation of a statement in the language.

The short answer is that trees are good at illustrating the Principle of Compositionality and are good tools visually and algebraically in what is known as a phrase structure grammar. From the WP article:

In a broader sense, phrase structure grammars are also known as constituency grammars. The defining character of phrase structure grammars is thus their adherence to the constituency relation, as opposed to the dependency relation of dependency grammars.

Why this is important is that the distance between words, psycholinguistically speaking, increases our ability to use lexemes in combinations to efficiently chunk meaning. For instance, in most languages, one tends to find modifiers immediately preceding or trailing nouns. This closeness in distance might be considered an ostention of sort, since the proximity allows for a rapid association to be perceived by the mind. Since trees are topographically predisposed to indicating proximity, it helps to show lexemic relationships graphically.
The other major type of grammar in linguistic theory is called the dependency grammar. This sort of grammar, IMNSHO, doesn't work as well because it deprives one the tool of 1:n relationships, a fact noted in the section comparing the PSG and DG. From WP:

Dependency is a one-to-one correspondence: for every element (e.g. word or morph) in the sentence, there is exactly one node in the structure of that sentence that corresponds to that element. The result of this one-to-one correspondence is that dependency grammars are word (or morph) grammars. All that exist are the elements and the dependencies that connect the elements into a structure. This situation should be compared with phrase structure. Phrase structure is a one-to-one-or-more correspondence

Why would you want to limit yourself by excluding 1 to n mappings? Yes, technically, one has a tree even if it's a strict sequence of populated nodes, but by attaching more than one populated node to parent node, it's possible to compress our graph.
From a computational standpoint (read NLP), trees allow us to parse grammars and build a data structure that are easy to deal with because we have a robust toolbox. In CS, it's common for parsers of any grammar to build abstract syntax trees (ASTs). ASTs improve computational efficiency because they minimize the distance between any two nodes in the tree. Consider a string with 1,000 tokens. From the first to the last token has a distance of 999. But collapse that into a binary tree (recall 210 is 1024), and we can potentially shorten the distance between two nodes to less than 10. There's also the strength that mathematical trees are amenable to recursion and processing by Turing machines which is an important property of more sophisticated grammars used in predicate logics and the like.
From a linguistic standpoint, trees also allow us to move around phrases as subtrees, a notion known originally as transformation. Thus, when Chomsky and others adopted the notion of transformation from historical linguistics and began experimenting with expressing deep structure, an idea related to syntactic synonymy of sentences, part of the solution was to simply show those transformations by showing a sequence of trees with rearranged nodes. Those nodes are frequently phrases represented as sub-trees which hints that it is not only syntax, but semantics that is preserved under such transformations.

@Lowri Your flagged and deleted answer wasn't a bad first guess. Since you broached regex, you might be interested in the broader Chomsky hiearachy, a schema for classifying several types of grammar.

Excellent answer ... one side note: Chomsky didn't invent transformations; they are a tool in traditional syntax analysis, which predates Chomsky by at least 2500 years. I don't know who first introduced transformations (e.g. putting a sentence into the passive voice to find the direct object), but it wasn't Chomsky.

@reinierpost I'm not sure I made the claim he invented them, though I probably would have thought Harris had, given my superficial knowledge of the history. :D I'll make sure I edit to make clear. Think I should include a bit about recursion? Trees as recursive structures seem like another cogent rationale for using them.

I don't think Chomsky made that claim, either, it's people who have read Chomsky who think a lot of linguistic concepts he took from traditional grammar were invented by him. Chomsky put them into a mathematical description (which he then revised several times).

You seem to be setting out dependency grammars as describing languages not "structured as trees", but surely these are at least as tree-structured as phrase-structured grammars.  Just recast the dependency relationship from "I depend on them" to "they depend on me" to flip the formal direction of all the depencies, and there's your tree, right there.

@JohnBollinger I knew a clever mind was going to zing me for relying on the intuitive use of tree (which is arguably a DAG), so I've tried to emend to recognize that dependency grammars technically use trees of the more trivial sense (such as the graphs presented in the WP article). Clearly, dependency grammars and transformations and the like have all sorts of technical minutia. Thanks for pointing out trees are technically broader than as I characterized them.


Is there something about the features languages need to have that prevents them from having other structures?

No. Trees are just a tool to visualize the meaning of statements to humans, in particular the syntax of sentences in formal languages.
However as soon as you want to discuss the semantics, many languages would need something beyond trees to understand references. Statements like the liars paradox can syntactically be represented as a tree, but that would not yet show any paradox. Only special languages not allowing references might be understandable with just a syntax tree.
Trivially it is impossible to define a tree syntax for graphs (without using tricks). While trees can be easily described using a bracket syntax, a graph like
A---B---C
|   |   |
D---E---F

would need references or convention to be able to be represented as a tree. We can express this by repeating the symbols in the language and declaring the same symbol represents the same entity:
A-B, B-C, A-D, D-E, E-F, B-E, C-F 

Another trick would be to represent this as an adjacency matrix marking which elements are connected to which others:
( A B C D E F ) # this line can be omitted in the grammar
A   x   x
B x   x   x
C   x       x
D x       x
E   x   x   x
F     x   x

But the initial little drawing I made makes the graph understandable immediately, as a visual language, even if that one does not allow tree-like representation of any graph. (Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57926758 for other ideas)
Yet another example are Venn diagrams in set theory.
Two dimensional text such as crossword puzzles or the befunge programming language (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Befunge) are similarly not suited well for tree-based representation.
Another example of a syntax that cannot that usefully be represented by a syntax tree might be musical score notation.

Why do languages so frequently have tree structures?

Typical languages serve human communication via voice or writing. So they need to be able to be put into a linear order that is relatively easy to follow. For trees there are simple (stateless) unambiguous traversal orders to serialize the tree into a sequence. But general graphs (with cycles) have no such simple traversal strategy (that grants exactly once visit of every node). So cycles present an obstacle in making languages useful for human communication via voice or writing.

I could define a language as a collection of symbols or elements, with rules for putting them together.

In formal language theory, this is typically done differently. Starting with abstract symbols, production rules describe the possibilities of creating sentences with non-abstract symbols. This approach is tree-likr and always allows to build a syntax tree in theory (though the Chomsky hierarchy determines whether and how this is minimally computable).

Voicing is key. It forces linearization, serialization, sequentiality (at least in current practice). So language structure is any structure recovered from a linear sequence. I'd say linearisable, but then I'd have to exclude contortions...

True, but trees are not the only graphs that can be "linearised". However they can be "linearised" without references in the syntax. And the human mind would be easily overwhelmed by keeping track of many syntactical references. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57926758

Why are languages commonly structured as trees?
Just as moonlight contains the solar spectrum, the tree structure of language reflects the recursive nature of our thoughts.
I went (to the store (down the street)) for bread.
Speech embeds the same structure implicitly in a linear way.
Don't be distracted by the pretty picture of a tree. It's only a way to represent recursion in two dimensions. It's like a sound spectrogram; it shows interesting information, but it's just a helpful representation of the real thing.

Language is a system of signs. A sign is a certain kind of relationship (1) between a signifier (2) and a signified (3). For example, a word (the sign) is a relationship connecting a sound (the signifier) to something in the world (the signified). So the concept of a sign implies no less than three elements.
If you then put the sign itself (the first element) into a relationship with another sign (e.g. by combining two terms into a proposition, or building a complicated concept on another more basic concept), this can again be analyzed as creating a relationship between signs, turning the sign into the signified element of a new sign. So by adding new elements, you continue to make structures of one symbolic element connecting two others. So a sign may increase to comprise more than three elements, but they are reducible to the same three in series of tree-like structures like you drew.
This is substantially the account given by semiotics (semioticians such as Saussure, Peirce, Barthes) to describe systems of signs such as language.


I could define a language as a collection of symbols or elements, with rules for putting them together.

Indeed, a language is a system of signs, generally used for communication (which also enables deliberate miscommunication and exclusion). @J_D gave an excellent answer to the question about the tree structure. I would only add to this that I believe this is the kind of surface structure that is present in syntagmatic relations - immediately underlying the sequential ordering of words. However, when we build non-formal language models, words (or word fragments) are represented as multidimensional vectors. These vectors represent the complicated semantic relations between different words, contexts and tasks (pragmatic tasks and whatever we mean by "meaning"). I believe that in our brains words are similarly represented -- as multidimensional vectors of some sort. This kind of relationship is not captured in any kind of simple tree structure; it's also not as easily accessible (or not accessible at all) to consciousness reflection.
But if you take a very general point of view, then there is no reason why "a language" would need more than one word or why more than one atomic sign would be necessary. You could for instance say that the language of newborns is like that: They either cry or they don't cry. Is that a language? Well, it's a sign - it means something. The parents will respond to it. It's not a subtle poetic language, but it does it's job (usually, hopefully), which is, first of all, simply, to draw attention to the miserable creature who is crying. (In Piercean terms it's an almost purely indexical sign.) -- You could argue that that is not a sign. However, I would argue that, even if in some sense it's not a sign, it will be interpreted as sign -- by the care givers -- and this, imperceptibly, is the beginning of the process of further language learning which ultimately results in the ability to express (only marginally more clearly): "Ouch! Stubbed my toe!"

Since this was tagged with "philosophy of computer science": the reason programming languages can usually be depicted this way is that it is much simpler to parse the language if the grammar adheres to that pattern with limited look-ahead for disambiguation. The standard tools for building parsers are built around that assumption.
For some details, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/LALR_parser and its "Relation to other parsers" section.
Humans are willing to do deeper speculative parsing, to disambiguate based on context and semantics, to accept probable rather than certain interpretation, to interpolate past apparent errors, and to add rules on the fly as they seem to be needed, so natural language is not reliably this regular. Sentence diagrams are still a useful pedagogical tool for analysing a formally correct sentence, since the formal rules tend to follow a similarly simple structure. It's possible that the underlying reason is the same as the computer cases, simplicity of parsing in isolation.
Note that sentence diagrams also benefit from having the entire sentence available, rather than trying to determine meaning on the fly. It might be interesting to have a tool which dynamically animates the process of natural language parsing as words arrive, showing all of the speculative structures that are built and discarded along the way.
For more about natural languages, I would strongly suggest taking this question to a linguistics stack or forum. That's the community that has done deep analysis of this. When you have a specialized branch of philosophy available, take advantage of it.

Human speech and writing is sequential, be it in time or in space, where each token can be structurally grouped together again and again, until we get a tree.
Why not any other graph? Well, if we were talking about actual meaning of words, we could indeed have graphs. But here we talk about grammar - word can't contain itself, otherwise it'd be infinitely long. Hence no cycles in our graphs, trees only.
That's also why in organic chemistry we have to parse chemical compounds into trees of atomic bonds whenever we name something - otherwise we can't spell it out or store it as plain text.

A directed graph can have a root and zero directed cycles while still having edges forming a cycle. So the strong statements about impossibility are wrong.

Also chemical notation is lossy to be possible, so it must drop some details: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Chemical_Identifier

Even undirected graphs with cycles can be traversed without infinite cycles, it just takes a stateful strategy (more effort).
